# Does the word "go" or "going" include the meaning of "be(ing)" or "stay(ing)"?

Tags: american-english

I hear a lot of people say:

"I am going to ***a-travel-destination*** from ***start-date*** till/to ***end-date***."

For example, "I am going to Hawaii from February 10th till the 17th.", or it can also be something like "I am planning to go to Europe from next week till the end of next month."

Although we do understand what they mean, doesn't the word ***go*** or ***going*** literally only mean the action of moving from point A to point B?

If so, the Hawaii example should literally mean that this person will be on the way to Hawaii from their location for 7 days (from 10th till 17th)?

Shouldn't this be instead said, "I am going to Hawaii and **stay/be there** from February 10th till the 17th." or something like this?

If not, then does the word ***go*** or ***going*** have a meaning of "be(ing)" or "stay(ing)" as well?

Every time I hear someone say "I am going blah blah from DATE till DATE.", it sounds so weird to my foreign ears (I am not a native English speaker).

Can someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one of the [definitions](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/go) of *go*

> 1.3 Attend or visit for a particular purpose.
>   *‘we went to the cinema’
>
>   ‘he went to Cambridge University’*

So going to Hawaii is like going to university -- it's not just the action of moving from one place to another, but being there for some period of time.